# Fuzziness in drawn frames (using canvas)

Tags: android, canvas, 2d

I'm hobby-writing a 2d game & I stumbled upon a certain problem.
My game is tile based (about 12x9 tiles) generally everything is fine, but from time to time when the character moves the frame becomes fuzzy and black segments appear.

My background is tile-based and I think it is caused by misplacing them.
In my opinion, it is happening because I have an update thread and a drawing thread that both work with the same variables, example:

```
private int x, y;
public void update() {x++; y += 2;}
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {canvas.drawBitmap(someImage, x, y);}
```

(Note: I just made this up so it will be a bit easier to understand what I am talking about.)

And the result is that there are (black) gaps between some of the tiles that are updated while drawn.

If I really am right, I guess I need to solve the critical-section problem.
So I tried just mutexing the data by syncing the threads and making them work in a serial way.
The result was really sad: it was REALLY slow on my galaxy S, absolutely unplayable!

My other idea (which I really don't wanna do) is to add a "drawAction" class to every drawable object in the game that will save a "snapshot" of it's object and only this collection of "snapshots" will be mutexed and so I can let the drawing thread do his work without being interrupted by the update thread.

Please share with me your ideas.
I hope you have better solutions or if I'm wrong about the problem, maybe you can help me gat to the source.

Edit:
My game generally works fine, but on slow devices (like the emulator) the interference is more visible.
When the player character doesn't move it is drown fine and **almost** always while walking.
I prefer to use only my code so I wold like to solve this problem and not just do a work around like using some engine or framework.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but it should help all the same. Consider using the game engine [AndEngine](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/). For 2D tile based games it is stupid smooth and really easy to learn.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use any 3rd party framework/engine that I do not absolutely must. Hope someone will come with another answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

The problem: I got a "writing" thread and a "reading" thread who used the dame source/destination.

I solved my problem by creating a "snapshot" or a "shadow" (technicly a copy..) of my mutual data right before the reading and hold the writing thriead while doing so, thus some of the read data was "old" but right to the same date with the rest.
The black things I saw were the differance in drawing (x, y) coused by updating the data while drawing it.